# How to use regex replace whilst preserving content

Tags: regex, replace, find, sublimetext2

I am using RegReplace https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace to run a regular expression find and replace in sublime text.

I want to add a new line either side of my tags. I know to select a tag the regex is `<(.*?)(.)>`.

What is the correct regex to add a mew line either side of the tag, without replacing the content? Something like `\n <(.*?)(.)> \n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead and `\K`

```
(?=<(.*?)(.)>)|<(.*?)(.)>\K
```

Replace the matched boundary with `\n` character.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eY7zI8/1)

**OR**

You could simply do like this,

```
(?=<[^<>]*>)|<[^<>]*>\K
```

Replace the matched boundary with `\n` character.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eY7zI8/2)